# How to add unique image class to Wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript, scripts

I want my in-image ads to appear only on the first long vertical images of my blog posts. I need to add a unique image class to the first images, but I don't know how to do this or what code to use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. You can do this by CSS or JavaScript too. The `:first-child` selector allows you to choose and modify the first element of each type.